# How to get Emberjs generated element id in controller

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, element

I would like to get the Ember generated id of an element.

```
{{#each}}
<div>
 <h1>{{MyComponent}}</h1>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

which render something like:

```
<div id="ember180" class="ember-view">
 <h1>My Component here</h1>
</div>
```

I need to get the id of each div element inside a controller. If I've to use custom id then how can I create custom id using ember view.

And how can I identify each div element by its id inside controller?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I can answer:

> And how can I identify each div element by its id inside controller?

[Working Example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nogogehowuyu/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output) Look at the console.log to see the element id, and then use Google Chrome or Firebug to inspect the component element to see that the id is the same.

```
App.ItemOneComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    console.log('element id: ' + this.elementId);
  }
});
```

`this` inside the component is the component, and elementId gets the `id` of the div (or different tag if you use `tagName` inside the component).

If you want to select the component with JQuery, use: `this.$()` inside of the component.

Now here is where I don't know what you need so I'm going to throw out a few suggestions. If you need to know the ids of every component from the controller, I would recommend passing in an array sitting on the controller to the component. In your `didInsertElement`, add the `elementId` or the `jQuery` object to the array.[Here is what I mean](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zoyafuzutiva/1/edit)

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  componentIds: []  
});

App.ItemOneComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    this.get('array').pushObject(this.elementId);
  }
});
```

And your component passes the property in: `{{item-one array=controller.componentIds}}`

You could also send the component's id or `jQuery` object via an action with `this.sendAction('actionName', componentId)` and have an action defined on your controller that takes one parameter (ie the componentId or the jQuery object.

Answer (score 4):

You can also deal with the emberId before it gets inserted into the html.

```
App.ItemOneComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    willInsertElement: function(){
        var emberId = this.get('elementId');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom id for your component by using the [elementId property](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.16/classes/Component/properties/elementId?anchor=elementId).

You can create the id by binding it to the component template like so

```
{{my-component elementId="your-id-name"}}
```

or in the component file

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  elementId: 'your-id-name'
});
```