# How does Ember.js generate ids?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159979/how-to-get-emberjs-generated-element-id-in-controller), using ember.js, this code:

```
{{#each}}
<div>
 <h1>{{MyComponent}}</h1>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

renders something like:

```
<div id="ember180" class="ember-view">
 <h1>My Component here</h1>
</div>
```

I'm interested in:

- How does ember decide which element would get a generated id?
- How does the id itself get generated?
- Is there any way to guarantee that the same element will always get the same id? (currently I'm seeing it changes every time)

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/utils.js#L220

Comment: What are you needing ids for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does ember decide which element would get a generated id?

All views (including components) get an ID so Ember can quickly find the element in the DOM. The only exception to this (that I know of) is that views without wrapper elements (`tagName` is an empty string) doesn't get an ID because there's technically no element to give an ID to.

> How does the id itself get generated?

As Yury pointed out, there's a private `Ember.guidFor()` method that assigns IDs to objects. Internally, it's just an incremented integer with a string prefix.

> Is there any way to guarantee that the same element will always get the same id? (currently I'm seeing it changes every time)

Definitely not, and even if there was I would highly suggest against using it. You can assign your own IDs to views and components and Ember will work with those instead of the generated one. If you need to know the ID of an element, [assign the ID yourself](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/customizing-a-views-element/#toc_customizing-a-view-s-element-from-handlebars).