# Ember customize id attribute of component

Tags: ember.js

Hi is there a way to customize the id of a component (i know it can be done for views ...but views have be deprecated since ember 1.13):

E.g. the following worked for the view:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
    classNames: ['music-js', 'vjs-default-skin', 'center-x','center-block'],
    attributeBindings: ['id'],
    id: 'musicOne',
```

However when I attempt to use id binding for the component  i get the exception in the console logs:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['music-js', 'vjs-default-skin', 'center-x','center-block'],
    attributeBindings: ['id'],
    id: 'musicOne',
```

Uncaught TypeError: The element or ID supplied is not valid.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I needed to initialize my jquery plugin in the didInsertElement lifecycle hook of the component

Comment: You should be able to do that with something like `Ember.$().init_my_plugin()`. without needing to specify the ID, unless the jQuery plug-in is imposing some funny requirements.

Comment: yeh the plugin in actually requires the id attribute to initialize

Comment: Override `elementId` in your component: https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_elementId

Comment: The `elementId` docs @AlanDong referred to have apparently moved: https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.18/classes/Component/properties/elementId?anchor=elementId

Answer (score 25, accepted):

2 ways:

In the component itself:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  elementId: 'the-id'
});
```

Or specifying it in the component call itself:

```
{{my-component id="the-id"}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but although that works, surely there must be a way to set it from inside the component itself, so that consumers of the component don't need to be concerned with having to do this?

Comment: @rmcsharry - There is. Use the `elementId` property inside the component. I've edited my post to make it more obvious that setting `elementId` does the trick.

Comment: Sorry, but your edit doesn't make it clear to a beginner. I still see how to specify it in the call, not how to set it inside. Do you mean you can just do this? {{my-component}} and then inside the component init call, do this.elementId = "the-id"?

Comment: You can also set `elementId` in the `init` lifecycle method: https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/Component/properties/elementId?anchor=elementId

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason for NOT being able to do this is that the component is automatically assigned an ID by the Ember framework itself. You can see that if you inspect the HTML when you run your app:

```
<div id="ember428" class="ember-view">
```

But you can get a handle on that auto-generated ID and pass that to the JQuery plugin, instead of creating your own ID as per Mikko's answer.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159979/how-to-get-emberjs-generated-element-id-in-controller) to learn how to do that.

I *think* this is the preferred way, since components should be 'isolated' from external dependencies. By having to pass in the ID from the template defeats that (as per Mikko's suggestion) - since any consumer of a component would have to know what ID to pass in for the component to work.

However, Mikko has now edited his answer, so setting your own ID inside the component, also satisfies the 'isolation' requirement (ie. using `elementID: 'the-id'`)