# EmberJS Add Animations to DIV for Fade Out and Fade In on Actions Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ember.js, animate.css

I am new to ember, but have almost finished what I set out to do. I just need to animate things as the final step.

I am using animate.css and animateCSS for my animations.

I have a set of  tags. When the user clicks on each button, i call the action onBtnClicked in my controller. When this button is clicked, I basically change the selectedImage property on my controller to a different URL. The selectedImage property automatically updates a  tag and the image is changed on the website.

What I would like to do is when the user clicks on the button, to run an animation to transitionOut the selectedImage and transitionIn the new image.

I am able to execute the animations, but the selectedImage updates too quickly and thus the new image is transitionedOut and transitionedIn.

If you have any advice on how to effectively handle the transition out animation it would be greatly aprpeciated.

Comment: Just change the class name of your graphic in the JavaScript. Something like `document.getElementById("myImage").className = "myFadingCss";`

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question to make it easier for people to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply first run transitionOut animation, and only when it's complete set the property. Something like this:

```
  actions: {
    select: function(item) {
      var me = this;
      Ember.$("img").fadeOut(function() {        
        me.set('currentImage', item);
        Ember.$("img").fadeIn();
      });
    }
  }
```

I've made a small demo with jQuery animations (animateCSS seem to use same callbacks) http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hiyatajeve

Comment: This is a fantastic Idea. Thanks for presenting me with a suitable solution. I intend on using this approach.

One question, I have a set of "components" that I would like to fadeOut/fadeIn when a user clicks on a button. However, I need a technique to get the component DIV element Ids. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: This link helped with accessing the component DIV element IDs [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159979/how-to-get-emberjs-generated-element-id-in-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Ember doesn't support animated transitions since when you transition out, it just removes the template partial from the DOM. And `Ember.View` hooks doesn't support promises.

I personally don't like managing views from controllers, this is another abstraction layer.

So I would recommend you to use [Liquid Fire Addon](http://ef4.github.io/liquid-fire/) which makes Ember to handle animated transitions in native way.